# Conditionally execute NLog target statement

Tags: c#, nlog

I have one Enum class given below

```
public enum ScanStatus
{
    Success,
    Failure,
    Exception
}
```

From .cs file I have passing the value of Exception to Nlog.config file using code

```
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("ExceptionStatus", Convert.ToString((int)ScanStatus.Exception));
```

In nlog.config, i have configured to log the message in database using below code.

```
<target name="database" xsi:type="Database" keepConnection="true"
           dbProvider="System.Data.SqlClient"
           connectionStringName="PaymentScan"
            commandText="INSERT INTO [dbo].[LoggingTrace] (PaymentId, ExceptionStatus, TraceDetails) VALUES (@ItemId, @ExceptionStatus, @Message)">
    <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}"/>
    <parameter name="@ItemId" layout="${gdc:ItemId}"/>
    <!-- custom field! -->
    <parameter name="@ExceptionStatus" layout="${gdc:ExceptionStatus}"/>
    <!-- custom field! -->
  </target>
```

I want this target statement should execute only when any exception occurs in the code. To handle this, I have written the rules given below

```
<rules>
<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="database">
        <filters>
          <when condition="equals('${gdc:ExceptionStatus}', '2')" action="Log" />
        </filters>
      </logger></rules>
```

I am facing issue that When exception does not occurs, the target is getting executed, means **equals** statement written in **rules** in not working. 
Could any body let me know the solution for this.

Comment: Have you tried the other way around setting the when filter as
`<when condition="not equals('${gdc:ExceptionStatus}', '2')" action="Ignore" />` ?

Comment: I got my answer. I need to put one extra **when** condition in **filters**. After that it is working as expected

Comment: Please update your post with the answer and mark is at answered. Thanks!